# Question about Neo4j + Flask log in Project

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, py2neo

[image] I am taking Nicole White's tutorials about Neo4i + Flask to make a blog page project. I run into this issue. I am using Python 3.7 and Py2neo v4 version. I am not sure about the User part. It gives me an error. It said 'User' object is not subscriptable.

If someone is good at neo4j and Flask, could you help me to take a look at that? I am a beginner in this field. I have attached the image to the link
[image: Click the link to view]

[image]

Comment: I would recommend the `neo4j` driver over the `py2neo` driver. It's the ofifical driver supported by Neo4j. I have found it to be quite good.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian.  I will take a look at that.